# Elementary Python: assigning characters to string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    for c in text:
        if c == "e":
            c = "2"
    return text
print anti_vowel("ee2ee")
```

Why does this print "ee2ee", not "22222"?

I said, whenever "e" comes out, replace it to "2".

I really can't understand.

Comment: Strings are immutable. Assigning `c = "2"` does not change the string.

Comment: Even if strings were mutable, assigning `c = "2"` still wouldn't change the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop over `text` by making consecutive copies of characters into `c`.
You only ever change `c`.

```
c = "2"
```

There is nothing which changes `text` before you return it.